# TypeError: get_object() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given [18/May/2021 18:27:12] "GET /api/Oxyegn/ HTTP/1.1" 500 94676

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

> What i am trying to do is i am giving Choice Field and i  am trying to
> get all post when i pass that choice field to url as parameter for eg:
> Oxygen, Plasma etc They are in my choice field which user has to
> choose during posting post.
>
> I want to get json format which we get whenever we do request to api
> and i want that information based to choice filed i have given but
> getting error.
>
> Rest Api View

```
class PostRestApi(APIView):
    def get_object(self, **kwargs):
        try:
            return Post.objects.get(help_type=kwargs.get('help_type'))
        except Post.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        posts = self.get_object(kwargs.get('help_type'))
        serializer = PostSerializer(posts)
        return Response(serializer.data)

> SERIALIZERS CLASS

class PostSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    title = serializers.CharField(max_length = 100)
    content = serializers.CharField()
    date = serializers.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now) 
    help_type = serializers.CharField()
        

My Post Model

CHOICES = (
    ("1", "Plasma"),
    ("2", "Oxygen"),
    ("3", "Bed"),
    ("4", "Emergency")
)

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now) 
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    help_type = models.CharField(max_length=300, choices = CHOICES, null=True)

url

path('api/<str:help_type>/', PostRestApi.as_view(), name='post-api')
```

Comment: Try this: `posts = self.get_object(help_type=kwargs.get('help_type'))` or `posts = self.get_object(**kwargs)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method `get_object` takes only keyword arguments other than the positional argument `self`, hence instead of:

```
posts = self.get_object(kwargs.get('help_type'))
```

You should be writing:

```
posts = self.get_object(help_type=kwargs.get('help_type'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs)` so then if you use `posts = self.get_object(kwargs.get('help_type'))` you can access `help_type=args[0]` or if you use `posts = self.get_object(help_type=kwargs.get('help_type'))` you can access `help_type=kwargs.get('help_type')`

Its best if you declare an attribute as such `def get_object(self, help_type, *args, **kwargs)` and use it like `return Post.objects.get(help_type=help_type)`

Answer (score 0):

```py
class PostRestApi(APIView):
    def get_object(self):
        try:
            return Post.objects.get(help_type=self.kwargs.get('help_type')) #Change1
        except Post.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        posts = self.get_object() #Change2
        serializer = PostSerializer(posts)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

- **#Change1:** `def get_object(self, **kwargs):` **changed to** `def get_object(self):` as get object takes self as the argument.
- **#Change2:** `posts = self.get_object(kwargs.get('help_type'))` **changed to** `posts = self.get_object()`, as kwargs can be accessed from the self argument.